# Submit specific forms in a specific order using Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms

I am fully aware that questions similar to this one have been posted here before. I cant find a way to solve my problem in the previous posts though.

I have two forms in a page that contains several other forms. When the submit button of the second form is clicked I would like the following to happen:

Form 1 is submitted and after that Form 2 is submitted.

But when the submit button of form1 is clicked, only form1 is submitted.

my code:

```
<form class='forms' id='form1'>
     <!--form content-->
     <button type='submit' id='submit-button-1'>Submit</button>
</form>

<form class='forms' id='form2'>
     <!--form content-->
     <button type='submit' id='submit-button-2'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

I know there is a way using AJAX to do this, but I have little to no experience with using AJAX.

Comment: You will have to submit forms with AJAX if you want two submissions.

Comment: Is there any limitation in the number of forms in your page?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```js
$("#form2").on("submit", function() {
  var $self = $(this);
  var $form1 = $("#form1");
  $.ajax({
    url: yourPSubmitUrl,
    data: $form1.serialize(),
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(result) {
      $self.submit();
    }
 });
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you submit a form normally, the response will replace the current page, so you can only submit one form that way.

To submit more than one form, you have to keep the current page from being replaced, at least for all but the last form.

- You can set the `target` attribute on a form to make the response go somewhere else, for example into an `iframe` on the page.
- You can use AJAX to post a form, then the response is returned to the Javascript instead of replacing the current page.

Comment: Using proper AJAX (like the answer that @Tim Osadchiy gave) doesn't require seperate iframe(s). I'd suggest iframes as an AJAX alternative, but not as means to an end.

Comment: @Leon: Naturally I didn't mean to use them both for the same form, but as two different ways of keeping the page from being replaced. I hope that the changed formatting made that clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I would define common event handler for both forms, but inside check what form is being submitted to decide if we need to submit second form after the first one.

In code it would look like this:

```
$('#form1, #form2').submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    // In both cases Form 1 is submitted first
    var submition1 = submitForm.call($('#form1')[0]);

    if (this.id === 'form2') {
        submition1.then(function() {
            submitForm.call($('#form2')[0]);
        });
    }

});

function submitForm() {
    return $.post(this.action, $(this).serialize());
}
```

For convenience I moved actual AJAX request to separate function.

The idea here is that the Form1 is submitted the first in both cases. So then if original submission comes from Form2 we simple chain to returned promise in order to schedule next submission after the first one is complete.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/ves2665v/

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked. One more question though, I use these form to submit data to a database. To save the data I need to refresh the page, is there a way to do this after these events?

Comment: Add this to refresh the page: `submitForm.call($('#form2')[0]).then(function() { location.href = location.href; });`.

Comment: Thank for your answer, I tried this but now form1 isn't saved. (well, it is saved, but I use the data from form 1 in form 2 and this isn't updated before form 2 is submitted, so form 2 contains the old data)

Nevermid, I'd put your line in the wrong place. Thanks!